# How to send file from system storage django?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I want to send file from my FileSystemStorage as response of a POST request, but every time i getting my error handler triggered. Why?

```
def get_frame(request):
    frame_number = request.POST['frame_number']
    filename = request.POST['filename']
    fss = FileSystemStorage()
    # creating name of file i need 
    name = f'frame_{frame_number}_{filename.replace(".mp4", "")}.png'
    # execute file path
    img = fss.path(name)
    return FileResponse(open(img, 'rb'))
```

script.js

```
for(let i=0; i<=frames_needed; i++) {
    let frame_number = fps * i
    // making POST request for 1 frame
    let img = get_each_frame(frame_number, filename)

    img.done(function(response) {
             console.log(response)
    })
    // getting this handler triggered
    img.fail(function(error) {
             console.log(error, 'error')
            })
        }
```

get_each_frame function

```
function get_each_frame(frame_number, filename) {
let request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_frame",
    data: {
        'frame_number': frame_number, 
        'filename': filename,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
    },
    dataType: "json",
});
return request
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imcij.png)

Comment: Plz share error details

Comment: @Eugenij done, but i dont have enough reputation to show it in post. Sorry